# Angular 11 compatibility with Internet Explorer 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Is there any way to Angular 11 be compatible to Internet Explorer 5? I'm developing an angular solution to a client and its default browser is Internet Explorer running document mode on version 5 (by default). At first I'm not suppose to change any browser configuration (i.e.: changing document mode to version 11 and set it default).

I'm using Angular 11.0.5 and Angular CLI 11.0.5:

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.5
Node: 14.16.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.0.5
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1100.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1100.5
@angular-devkit/core               11.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics         11.0.5
@angular/cdk                       11.0.3
@angular/material                  11.0.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter   12.0.4
@schematics/angular                11.0.5
@schematics/update                 0.1100.5
rxjs                               6.6.3
typescript                         4.0.5
```

There is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge; IE=11; IE=10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=5" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cronograma</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>



</html>
```

I tried also to change `<!doctype html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" />` but nothing happens.

There is my src/polyfills.ts:

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */

import 'core-js/es/reflect';
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/promise';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.

import 'classlist.js';
import 'web-animations-js';

/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Comment: Angular 12 deprecates IE 11... It might be time to ask your client to move off of Window 98...

Comment: There is no way you can charge somebody running IE5 enough to make it worth your while to develop an application for IE5.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Absolutely no. Angular 2+ never supported IE5 (and I doubt even Angular.js did back in the day). You can see the list of supported browsers [here](https://v11.angular.io/guide/browser-support) - the oldest IE supported is 11.

No idea why your client uses such an old and insecure browser, but a single page application is not a feasible solution in this case.